# Rmarkdown to html on windows: DT::datatable not rendering (suspect pandoc issue)

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, htmlwidgets

Fails to render with `pandoc.exe: \\: openBinaryFile: does not exist`

`rmarkdown::pandoc_available()` is `TRUE`

Anyone ever seen anything like this?

Also, fwiw, there is not much CSS going on. No boxes around code chunks, etc.

Comment: Have you been able to render rmarkdown in the past? or is this the first time trying to render? maybe try installing another latex program.

Comment: No latex—we are rendering to HTML. Only need latex to render PDF, no? Installing latex will take months as I am constrained to the archaic ecosystem of a dinosaur business company laptop.

Comment: hmm you might be right about that, apologize, still learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the file path you are using, are you using a relative file path, or an absolute file path? Are you pulling a file from a network drive? Double check you spelled the file correct. I am asking these questions, because I believe it might be as simple as the error is just not able to open the file, due to an incorrect file path / incorrect file name

Comment: Yes to network drive—incorrect naming of which file, the `.Rmd`? If so, I have tried both clicking "Knit" as well as running the command `rmarkdown::render("Test.rmd")`

Comment: Are you reading in a file for data? not the .Rmd file.

Comment: Yes reading data file but those load no problem as I verified with some random print statements. The knit does not fail till the very end.